# Prolog coordinate checking

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to look through a lists of lists and return true if a specified value appears twice in a given row. e.g.

```
%B is a list of lists such the positions of x are denoted by the values
[[1,1],[2,3],[3,2]] would be visualized like:
x--
--x
-x-
```

and these coordinates would be represented by B
so a method foo(B) where B =

```
[[1,1],[1,3],[2,3],[3,3]] = true
```

as x would appear twice in row one.

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: I don't have an attempt, I'm new to prolog and don't even know where to start.

Comment: You should start learning a little Prolog. Do a tutorial. Also you can explore [99 Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/) which has lots of simple list processing examples with solutions. You'd start by thinking about what does a list look like if x is twice in one row.  It says that two elements in your list have the same first coordinate. So for each element in your list, `[X, _]` (I don't care what the second coordinate is), you want to succeed if it's a member of the rest of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment section, you need to check if two pair in the list have the same X coordinate. So, the first solution that comes to mind could be something like this (added some writeln to desplay the values):

```
solution1(L):-
    member([X,Y1],L),
    member([X,Y2],L),    
    writeln([X,Y1]),
    writeln([X,Y2]).
```

The presicate `member/2` checks if the first element is present in the list passed as second parameter. Running the query `?- solution1([[1,1],[1,3],[2,3],[3,3]]).` we get the following result:

```
?- solution1([[1,1],[1,3],[2,3],[3,3]]).

[1, 1]
[1, 1]
true
[1, 1]
[1, 3]
true
[1, 3]
[1, 1]
true
[1, 3]
[1, 3]
true
[2, 3]
[2, 3]
true
[3, 3]
[3, 3]
true
```

Mmm, a lot of solutions and not quite what we want. One of the problem is that, written in this way, `member/2` checks in the whole list so we get a solution in every case because every pair selected with the first call to `memeber/2` is in the list. With the second `member/2` we can select the same element so the predicate succeeds. 
In order to avoid this behaviour, we can write the predicate as follows:

```
solution2([[A,_]|T]):-
    member([A,_],T).
solution2([[_,_]|T]):-
    solution2(T).
```

With this second predicate we check if the selected element is present in the rest of the list and so we exclude the element itself from the search and we get only one solution.

```
?- solution2([[1,1],[1,3],[2,3],[3,3]]).
true
false
```

Note that this is a very simple implementation, maybe there are better methods to solve this problem.